# How to understand output of netstat( below ) command?

Tags: findstr, netstat

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>netstat -nao | findstr 27000

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:27000          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4848
  TCP    127.0.0.1:18107        127.0.0.1:27000        ESTABLISHED     1168
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27000        127.0.0.1:18107        ESTABLISHED     4848
  TCP    [::]:27000             [::]:0                 LISTENING       4848
  TCP    [fe80::b174:a291:3c63:8e7f%14]:18104  [fe80::b174:a291:3c63:8e7f%14]:27000  TIME_WAIT
```

0

Comment: What is your question? What part of the output don't you understand? (And how is this a programming question?)

Comment: I mean what can I conclude from port 4848 and 1168 ? Is the service listening on port 27000 or is it on 4868 or 1168 ?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and ask that there, where people can see it, instead of burying it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments to your question above:

> I mean what can I conclude from port 4848 and 1168 ? Is the service listening on port 27000 or is it on 4868 or 1168 ?

You can conclude that you're not reading the column headers for the output. The column containing the `4848` and `1168` is headed **PID**, which is **Process ID**. It has nothing to do with the port.

The columns are (in order, left to right - I've added the headings to your output):

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID 
TCP    0.0.0.0:27000          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4848
TCP    127.0.0.1:18107        127.0.0.1:27000        ESTABLISHED     1168
TCP    127.0.0.1:27000        127.0.0.1:18107        ESTABLISHED     4848
TCP    [::]:27000             [::]:0                 LISTENING       4848
TCP    [fe80::b174:a291:3c63:8e7f%14]:18104  [fe80::b174:a291:3c63:8e7f%14]:27000  TIME_WAIT
```

Comment: it mean that PID( 4848 ) is running on the port(27000) and PID ( 1168 ) is running on port( 18107 ). Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, it means that PID 4848 is connected locally on port 27000 on localhost (IP 127.0.0.1), and there's a process 1168 on the same IP, port 18107. (It's two sides of a communication, it appears.)